# Getting strange crash while decoding html data using NSAttributedString

Tags: swift

Getting strange crash while decoding html data using NSAttributedString,please find below function and crash logs. While trying to decoding a weird crash occurs

```
    func decodeHTML() -> String {
        var attributedString = NSAttributedString(string :self)
        let encodedData = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        let attributedOptions : [String: Any] = [
            NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
            NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue
        ]
        //webkitlegacy crash. It should run in main thread

        if Thread.isMainThread {
            do {
                attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
            } catch {
                print("Unexpected error occured inside decodeHTML")
            }
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                do {
                    attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
                } catch {
                    print("Unexpected error occured inside decodeHTML")
                }
            }
        }
        return attributedString.string
    }
}    

I got below crash logs , please let me know how to avoid such crash
```

getting following log:

> 0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x18b332f30 objc_msgSend + 16
>       1  WebKitLegacy                   0x19242a25c -[_WebSafeForwarder forwardInvocation:] + 132
>       2  CoreFoundation                 0x18c8ea078 ***forwarding*** + 404
>       3  CoreFoundation                 0x18c7e459c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
>       4  CoreFoundation                 0x18c8ec160 **invoking_** + 144
>       5  CoreFoundation                 0x18c7dfc3c -[NSInvocation invoke] + 284
>       6  WebCore                        0x19139ac78 HandleDelegateSource(void*) + 108
>       7  CoreFoundation                 0x18c894278 **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 24
>       8  CoreFoundation                 0x18c893bc0 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 524
>       9  CoreFoundation                 0x18c8917c0 __CFRunLoopRun + 804
>       10 CoreFoundation                 0x18c7c0048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
>       11 UIFoundation                   0x1926e919c -[NSHTMLReader _loadUsingWebKit] + 1860
>       12 UIFoundation                   0x1926ea424 -[NSHTMLReader attributedString] + 28
>       13 UIFoundation                   0x192689cb4 _NSReadAttributedStringFromURLOrData + 4688
>       14 UIFoundation                   0x1926889bc -[

Comment: If you are not in main thread, you use a dispatch, but your returned value won't be correct since it's return before the end of the conversion. Could you check if your issue occurs only in that case or in the other one?

Comment: Since @Azhar is using `DispatchQueue.main.sync`, it should block and not return preliminary

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
extension String {
 init(htmlEncodedString: String) {
    self.init()
    guard let encodedData = htmlEncodedString.data(using: .utf8) else {
        self = htmlEncodedString
        return
    }
    
    do {
       let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html] , documentAttributes: nil)
        self = attributedString.string
    } catch {
        print("Error: \(error)")
        self = htmlEncodedString
    }
  }
}
```

Call above method like below  -

```
 let html = "<center>Here is some <b>HTML</b></center>"
    let decodedString = String(htmlEncodedString: html)
    print(decodedString)
```

Comment: `Cannot convert value of type 'NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey' to expected dictionary key type 'NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey'` and `Cannot convert value of type 'NSAttributedString.DocumentAttributeKey' to expected dictionary key type 'NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey'` .... Its giving the error on both `NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
        NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue` lines ..

Comment: @WahabKhanJadon - Updated code. you can try using updated ans. Thanks